# Compressed email attachments for logrotate

Tags: apache-2.2, logrotate

How can I configure logrotate so that it emails me the files 'after' they have been compressed? Right now I am emailed the uncompressed files which can results in huge attachments.

Answer (score 1):

logrotate  (3.7.8-1) in Debian has a patch "[sharedscripts-519432.patch](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?msg=32;filename=sharedscripts-519432.patch;att=1;bug=519432)" which will give the rotated log as an argument to postrotate scripts. It could be used to mail the compressed file.